# jQuery tabs: how to create a link to a specific tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, hyperlink

Hello I already found this topic : [jQuery tabs: how to create a link to a specific tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601035/jquery-tabs-how-to-create-a-link-to-a-specific-tab)

But that not resolve my problem,

here my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    e.preventDefault();         
    yInitPos = $(window).scrollTop();       
    // On ajoute le hash dans l'url.
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

    return false;
});
});
```

I can't acces to a tab with link like this : http://127.0.0.1/admin.php#tab2

Can you help me ? Thanks

Comment: You do know we can't follow that link, right?

Comment: How does the answer in the linked question not help? It contains the solution here - `var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); $(activeTab).show();`

Comment: in the code above, you aren't making use of the "solution" to the topic you referenced... that would probably help.

Comment: provide your html code as well so that we can help quickly

Comment: I just do it just after, thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this below script, just made once change to the // on ajoute le hash dans

and added some code below the click function

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Default Action
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function(e) {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        e.preventDefault();         
        yInitPos = $(window).scrollTop();       
        // On ajoute le hash dans l'url. 
// $(this) below will be <li> tag, so you have to get to the children <a> tag with href attr
        window.location.hash = $(this).children().attr("href");

        return false;
    });
// the code below gets the hash(#) value from the url and finds the link with a href of this # value and triggers it
    var tabId = window.location.hash;
    console.log(tabId);
    if(tabId !== "")
    {
        $(".tabs").find('a[href='+tabId+']').click();
    }

});
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! That's work, what are the differences with the solution that was given in the link I put?

Comment: added this new to your code
var tabId = window.location.hash;
     console.log(tabId);
     if(tabId !== "")
     {
      $(".tabs").find('a[href='+tabId+']').click();
     }

and changed the line so it gets the right element
// On ajoute le hash dans l'url.
        window.location.hash = $(this).children().attr("href");

Comment: oh ok thank you, I was stuck on it for a few hours. Have a good day.